# How to create Expression Trees - pseudo code

Tags: tree

can you help me, how can i build Expression Trees from String text = "(3-2*3)/(3/2)+3";.

I found no useful guidance with which I understand ..

I ask you for advice on how to proceed in pseudo code..

```
for(text.lenght){

add to tree ..?

}
```

Thak you.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library to do this in C#/.NET, you can see the code here: https://github.com/youknowjack1/mathexpressionparser